# Synthesis Error Reading and Output Port

Tags: vhdl

I am getting a synthesis error when reading this line of code:

```
a <= '1' when x > y else '0';    
b <= c when a = '1' else B"000";
```

The error is:

```
   xxx:    b <= c when a = '1' else B"000";
                       ^
[Error] Read error: trying to read port of mode OUT
```

a is the read port.  How can I avoid reading a and still accomplishing what I need ?

Comment: can you show your whole component?

Comment: You could turn on VHDL-2008 in the compile options.

Comment: Use an internal signal instead of a. And then assign a<= internal signal;

Comment: It appears 'a' is an output in your module ( a : OUT STD_LOGIC; ). It is not legal to read an OUT port. You have to do what Mitu Raj suggested, create a signal ( SIGNAL a_int : STD_LOGIC;), do all your manipulation on that, and only at the very end assign it to your OUT port (a <= a_int;)

Comment: Since the introduction of the old standard of [VHDL-2008](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4772740), it has been legal to read an OUT port. Watch the [Doulos video](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl/vhdl-2008/).

Comment: Cool! Thanks @tim, I learned something today. I do suspect the problem is user isn't using -2008, or is using a compiler that doesn't fully support -2008 (always a danger when taking advantage of these new whizbang features).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a signal to use internally:

```
signal temp_a : std_logic ;
```

And use that signal in your logical expressions:

```
temp_a <= '1' when x > y        else '0'   ;    
b      <= c   when temp_a = '1' else B"000 ;
```

And finally assign it to `a` concurrently in the architecture:

```
a <= temp_a ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you seem to be using `a` as if you expect it to act like a variable rather than a signal (but other parts of your design may also use it as a signal--impossible to guess based on what you've posted).

So depending on if/how you use it elsewhere, you might:

1. make `a` a variable, or
2. make `a` an `in_out` signal, or
3. you might change the second line to something like:

   ```
   b <= c when x > y else B"000";
   ```

   [...which is pretty much the same thing as option 1 above].
4. Add a variable that's used both in setting `a` and `b`. For example, what does x being greater than y actually *mean*? Define a variable with a name that reflects that actual meaning, and then use that variable both when setting `a` and `b`.

   ```
    inRange := x > y;
    a <= inRange;
    b <= c when inRange else B"000";
   ```

Which of these is preferred will depend. If `a` really needs to be a signal, then the first option is simply ruled out.

So, if `a` is just being used inside this process, then making it a variable is the obvious choice.

If `a` really needs to be a signal, then I'd probably prefer the fourth option as a rule.

Comment: I do like option 3 here as making the code clearer.

Comment: Problem is I still need to send a to be equal to 1 based on x>y or a goes to 0.  Can I set up an if statement for this ?

Comment: @user4434: In that case, I'd probably go for the (newly added) fourth option. But yes, you could also use an `if` statement. `if x > y then a <= '1'; b <= c; else a <= '0' ; b <= B"000"; end if`